# Update fails to compile stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to add this update statement to a stored procedure that has a few insert statements ahead of it. I'm getting ORA-00933 when i try to compile but I don't see any issues. I will say that I am used to SQL Server so forgive me if this is something silly in terms of Translation to Oracle.

```
UPDATE
  APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS
SET
  I_FK_TLINK_TEAM = SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS.I_SK_TLINK_TEAM
FROM
  SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS
LEFT JOIN
  CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS@SHG_SPECIALIST
  ON
    SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS.A_FORENAME = CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.FIRST_NAME
    AND
    SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS.A_SURNAME = CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.LAST_NAME
LEFT JOIN
  SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS
  ON 
    CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.TEAM_NAME = SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS.A_TEAMNAME
WHERE
  SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS.I_SK_TLINK_TEAM <> APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS.I_FK_TEAM;
```

I can provide (if required) the entire stored procedure should anyone need it.

Many thanks as always :)

Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support the `UPDATE... FROM` construct that SQL Server does. You should use a [MERGE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) instead. It should be something like:

```
MERGE INTO APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS A
USING
(
SELECT SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS.I_SK_TLINK_TEAM
FROM
  SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS
LEFT JOIN
  CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS@SHG_SPECIALIST
  ON
    SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS.A_FORENAME = CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.FIRST_NAME
    AND
    SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_AGENTS.A_SURNAME = CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.LAST_NAME
LEFT JOIN
  SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS
  ON 
    CMS_W_AGENT_DETAILS.TEAM_NAME = SHG_DATAW.APEX_QC_TLINK_TEAMS.A_TEAMNAME

) B
ON (B.I_SK_TLINK_TEAM <> A.I_FK_TEAM)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.I_FK_TLINK_TEAM = B.I_SK_TLINK_TEAM;
```